# Will iOS 8 allow third party apps to delete photos from the library?

Tags: ios, photos

Does anyone know if iOS 8 will allow a third party app to delete photos from the library on the phone? I want to make an app that has the ability to view all photos directly from the photos library on an iPhone then have the ability to delete them. I will also need the ability to create new folders in the photos library and move photos into the new folders. The documentation is not clear if this will be possible in iOS 8. Currently this is not possible in iOS 7.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAssetChangeRequest/deleteAssets:)?

Answer (score 2):

You asked multiple questions. I will answer what I know for iOS 7.

- Yes, you can create custom folders in Photo Album.
- Yes, you can add photos to those custom albums. Those photos are just "pointers" to the real photos in the "Camera Roll" folder.
- Yes, you can delete your custom folders
- NO third party app can delete photos from a user Camera Roll. Only a user can do that himself.

I am assuming all these statements are true for iOS 8. I haven't see anything in WWDC suggesting otherwise.